# Excel Formatting for Symbols

Tags: formatting, conditional-formatting

Can someone please explain how to do this:

I have two columns (A&B). Column A shows days of the week, while column B shows the pass or fail symbols for each day (see attached). How can i formulate the log where the success rate row (A11), automatically populates the success rate, as a %, (in B11) in terms of the amount of pass symbols over the fail symbols. E.g. in the log, the pass mark is 6 days out of 10. I want the success rate column (B11) to automatically show 60%. Can you kindly explain how to do that?

[image]

Comment: If you have inserted Tick Mark symbol from Symbol --> Wingdings --> Character 252, then just put CHAR(252) in countif formula to count the Ticks.  =COUNTIF(B1:B10,CHAR(252))/COUNTA(B1:B10). Also you may use CHAR(251) for cross mark.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an additional column C that contains the values `Yes` or `No`.

The success rate for 10 elements will then be (10 = 100 / 10):

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10,"Yes") * 10
```